# Adicionar funções em kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, kivy

Sou iniciante em python e em programação no gera, estou fazendo um projeto para a feira de ciências da escola e preciso de ajuda para adicionar está função à minha interface gráfica(estou utilizando python 3.6 e estou no Ubuntu):

class Assistente(Screen):

```
def frase(self):
    resp = input('Olá! O meu nome é AVUSA. A sua Assistente Virtual para o Uso Sustentável da Água.\n'
                   'Você você precisa de assistência  quanto ao controle do uso de água na sua residência?')

    if resp == 'sim':
        temChuv = int(input('Então vamos lá! Quanto tempo, em minutos, você gasta debaixo do chuveiro em um dia?:'))

        Lbanho = temChuv * 6

        temVaso = float(input('Beleza! Quantas descargas você costuma dar em um dia?:'))

        LVaso = temVaso * 12

        tempb = float(input('Ok! Quanto tempo, em minutos, você gasta usando a pia do banheiro em um dia?:'))

        Lpb = tempb * 5

        tempc = float(input('Ok! Quanto tempo, em minutos, você gasta usando a pia da cozinha em um dia?:'))
        Lpc = tempc * 6

        temTan = float(input('Ok! Quanto tempo, em minutos, você gasta usando o tanquinho, em um dia?'))
        LTan = temTan * 15

        temMaq = float(input('Beleza! Quantas vezes você utiliza a máquina de lavar roupas por semana?:'))
        LMaq = temMaq * 12

        TotalpDia = float(Lbanho + LVaso + Lpc + Lpb + LMaq + LTan)
        TotalpMes = float(TotalpDia * 31)
        AcreDia = (TotalpDia * 3.14 / 1000)
        AcreMes = (31 * AcreDia)
        conredu = float(AcreMes - 10.54)

        print('Você consome cerca de {:.2f} litros de água por dia!\n'.format(TotalpDia))
        print('E em um mês você consome cerca de {:.2f} litros de água!\n'.format(TotalpMes))
        print(
            'Isto representa um acréscimo de cerca de R${:.2f} por dia e R${:.2f} por mês na sua conta de água\n'.format
            (AcreDia, AcreMes))

        if TotalpDia > 110.0:
            print('A ONU (Organização das Nações Unidas) diz que 110.0 litros por dia são suficientes para\n'
                  'atender as necessidades básicas de consumo e higiene de uma pessoa. ')

            print(
                'Portanto, caso você reduza seu consumo de água de {:.2f} para 110 litros por dia. Conseguirá\numa redução de '
                'cerca de R$ 10.54 na sua conta de água, que passará a ser R${:.2f}, e estará fazendo a sua parte no uso consciente deste recurso.'.format(
                    TotalpDia, conredu))

        else:
            print(
                'Parabéns! Você está dentro do limite do uso diário de água estipulado pela ONU (Organização das Nações Unidas')


    elif resp == 'não':
        print('Tá bom. Se precisar, estarei sempre à sua disposição! :)')
```

test.kv:

Menu:
        name:'menu'

```
Tarefas:
    name:'tarefas'

Assistente:
    name:'assistente'
```

:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:root.width*0.32, root.height*0.25
        spacing:'25dp'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos

```
    Image:
        source:'logo.png'
        size_hint_y:2.3
        allow_strech:True

    Botao:

        text:'Tarefas'
        on_release:app.root.current = 'tarefas'
        on_release:app.root.transition.direction = 'right'
    Botao:
        text:'Assistente'
        on_release:app.root.current = 'assistente'
        on_release:app.root.transition.direction = 'left'

    Botao:
        text:'Sair'
        on_release:root.confirmacao()
```

:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos

```
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                title:'Tarefa'
                on_release:app.root.current = 'menu'


            ActionButton:
                text:'Sair'
                on_release:app.stop()

    ScrollView:
        BoxLayout:
            id:box
            orientation:'vertical'
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height
            color:0,0,0,1   

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y:None
        height:'40sp'
        TextInput:
            id:texto

        Button:
            text:'+'
            size_hint_x:None
            width:'40sp'
            on_release:root.addWidget()
            background_color:(0,1,2,1)
```

:
    size_hint_y:None
    height:'100sp'
    Splitter:
        strip_size:'3pt'
        sizable_from:'bottom'
        Label:
            id:label
            font_size:'20sp'
            color:0,0,0,1

```
Button:
    text:'X'        
    size_hint_x:None
    width:'40sp'
    on_release:app.root.get_screen('tarefas').removeWidget(root)
    background_color:(0,1,2,1)
```

:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos

```
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                title:'Assistente'
                on_release:app.root.current = 'menu'

            ActionButton:
                text:'Sair'
                on_release:app.stop()

    ScrollView:
        BoxLayout:
            id:box
            orientation:'vertical'
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height
            color:0,0,0,1   

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y:None
        height:'40sp'
        TextInput:
            id:texto

        Button:
            text:'>'
            size_hint_x:None
            width:'40sp'
            background_color:(0,1,2,1)
            on_release:??????????????
```

Answer (score 0):

O comando pra ser referir a uma função pelo código `kv` seria algo parecido com `on_press: root.funcao()`, mas pra isso, primeiro você teria que construir uma interface gráfica com `input`, `output` e botões bem definidos, e não somente rodar a função com o código que Python inteiro.

Refiz um pouco da sua ideia para você ver como funcionaria (e para chamar a função usei uma sintaxe que funciona no lado Python da aplicação, que seria o método `bind`).

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout  import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (360, 640)
Window.clearcolor = [.85, .85, .85, .85]

class RootBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.upperbox = BoxLayout(id = 'upper', orientation = 'vertical')
        self.add_widget(self.upperbox)

        self.ti = TextInput(id = 'textinput', text= 'Deseja começar? pressione Sim ', font_size = 30)
        self.upperbox.add_widget(self.ti)

        self.submitbox = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', padding=30)
        self.upperbox.add_widget(self.submitbox)

        self.btns = Button(id = 'btns', text = 'submit', font_size = 30)
        self.btns.bind(on_press=self.click) #conecta o evento on_press a execução da função click
        self.btns.disabled = True #desabilita botão por default, será habilitado denovo depois pressionamento do botão 'sim'
        self.submitbox.add_widget(self.btns)

        self.si = TextInput(id = 'submitinput', font_size = 30)
        self.submitbox.add_widget(self.si)

        self.lowerbox = BoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.lowerbox)

        self.btn1 = Button(id = 'btn1', text = 'Sim', font_size = 30)
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.fraseinicial)
        self.lowerbox.add_widget(self.btn1)


    controle =0
    def click(self, num):
        self.controle += 1
        if self.controle ==1:
            self.temchuv = int(self.si.text)
            self.Lbanho = self.temchuv * 6
            print('Lbanho: ', self.Lbanho)
            self.si.text = ''
            self.ti.text ='Beleza! Quantas descargas você costuma dar em um dia?'
            self.controle += 1

        elif self.controle ==3:  
            self.temvaso = int(self.si.text)
            self.LVaso = self.temvaso * 12
            print('LVaso: ', self.LVaso)
            self.si.text = ''
            self.strb = str(self.Lbanho)
            self.strv = str(self.LVaso)
            self.ti.text = "Ok, seu gasto com chuveiro é de " + self.strb + " e gasto com descarga é de " + self.strv
            self.controle += 1

        elif self.controle ==5:
            print('4º output depois do click()')
            self.controle += 1

        elif self.controle ==7:
            print('5º output depois do click()')
            self.controle += 1

        elif self.controle ==9:
            print('etc etc etc')
            self.controle += 1

        else: pass


    def fraseinicial(self, num):
        self.btns.disabled = False
        self.ti.text ='Então vamos lá! Quanto tempo, em minutos, você gasta debaixo do chuveiro em um dia?'
        self.btn1.disabled = True



class PrincipalApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 1.11.0
<RootBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    """)
        return RootBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PrincipalApp().run()
```